# The version of iOS on phone is not supported by this iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a mac at home (10.9.2) with Xcode 5.1.1 and at work (10.9.5) with xcode 5.1.1.  I have a developer account at work and was able to test on my phone.  I just set up a developer account at home and got my phone set up to test there as well.  Now at work Xcode doesn't recognize my phone.  I went to organizer and I get this message:

> The version of iOS on "my phone" is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK.  Please restore the device to a version of the iOS listed below or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK. OS Installed on my phone 8.0

What do I need to do in order to use my phone for work and personal development?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of iOS is on the phone?

Comment: Why aren't you using Xcode 6?

Comment: Xcode 6 kept locking up on me but I was using it side by side with Xcode5. I uninstalled 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 5.1.1 does not officially support debugging on iOS 8 devices.

You would need to install Xcode 6 to debug on iOS 8 devices.

I've had some success using Xcode 5 to debug on iOS 8 after installing (and running so it installs the support components) Xcode 6 alongside Xcode 5.1.1. I presume this isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: The 1st line of this answer is misleading since you then go on to state how you can actually debug iOS 8 devices with Xcode 5.

Comment: @maddy Fair point; updated to make it clear that (as far as I know) that it's not officially supported as far as I know.

Comment: My phone is 8.  I have tested and used it before with Xcode5.

Comment: @KFP But in order for Xcode 5 to recognize an iOS 8 device, Xcode 6 must be connected to the device at least once on the same computer as Xcode 5.

Comment: I've used this phone(iOS8) with my home mac which has Xcode 5.1.1.  I've tested my apps on it..though instruments isn't working and gives me errors.

Comment: @KFP You state in your question that the problem is on your work computer. So you need to use Xcode 6 on your work computer and connect it to your iOS 8 iPhone. Then Xcode 5 will work on your iPhone on the work computer.